# requests.get() giving an error while fetching data

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm still at learning phase of python. So, here's what I was trying to do. I was fetching the data off of the accuweather page to show the current weather. But requests module seems to give some sort of error.

```
> import requests
> from bs4 import *
> data = requests.get("https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/new-york-ny/10017/weather-forecast/349727")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1009, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 871, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
timeout=timeout
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 357, in increment
raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1009, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 871, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
data = requests.get("https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/new-york-ny/10017/weather-forecast/349727")
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Comment: Seems like the site you are trying to access has restrictive measures, and if l am not mistaken you need a key for the API for accuweather.

Comment: For your usage, it seems that [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) might be more adapted.

Comment: @IMCoins why is selenium more adapted? He is making HTTP requests, so the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library is perfectly fine

Comment: It seems to me that he wants to make some webscrapping (collecting data from webpage), and as a beginner (I understood this with `I'm still at learning phase of python`), I thought I'd recommend selenium to him as I have read a hell lot about easy webscraping with selenium. But you're right,  _more adapted_ doesn't fit here. @Bart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sites change their HTTP response code or content, or drop the connection for HTTP requests with `requests`'s default User-Agent header.

In this case all you have to do is change the User-Agent string in `headers`, eg

```
import requests

url = "https://www.accuweather.com/en/us/new-york-ny/10017/weather-forecast/349727"
data = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'my agent'})
print(data)
```

---

```
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: I am wondering : how are you supposed to know these informations like "some sites do this, other this". Do you just learn these conventions by experience or is there an official site where it is documented ?

Comment: @IMCoins mostly by trial and error, starting with User-Agent and Referer.